# How to display link conditionally based on the site's language using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wpml

I'm trying to display link conditionally in a .JS file in wordpress using WPML. I've tried the following but now working;

```
var getLangCode = <?php echo '"' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE . '"' ; ?>; //WPML code to detect site's language. Getting error on this line
    if (getLangCode === 'en-US') {
        var imagesPath = 'https://website-domain.com/file-name.jpg';
    }else if (getLangCode === 'fr-FR') {
        var imagesPath = 'https://website-domain.com/fr/file-name.jpg';
    }
```

I'm getting the following error on the above line `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I'm using the link to add image and text to a container... the text works fine, as i have used `wp_localize_script` to make the string Translateable but when i switch to french, the image doesn't show anymore because the link now contains `fr`

Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated

Comment: The first line of code includes PHP, which does not get processed inside of a js file.  There's workarounds, but that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, can you please point in the right direction to getting the error fixed?

Comment: You bet.  See this article: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/pass-php-variable-to-javascript

Comment: Gone through the link and still don't know how I can use wp_localize_script to solve my question ... I'm already using the function to localize contents in the JS file (as state in my question) but have no idea how to do this conditional link with same method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using wp_localize_script, I'd use this to pass not only the translations but your language code as well, as stated in some of the comments and the tutorial. Like this:

*In WordPress*

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your_javascript.js' );

$dataToBePassedtoJS = array(
    'language_code'    => ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE,
    'translate_string' => __( 'Translate me!', 'default' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handler', 'php_vars_for_js', $dataToBePassedtoJS );
// the 'php_vars_for_js' will be an object in JS, 
// it's properties will be the content of the dataToBePassedtoJS array.
```

*In your javascript*

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    // get the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE passed by wp_localize_script's 'php_vars_for_js' to your JS:
    var getLangCode = php_vars_for_js.language_code; 

    // show it in the console, just for fun
    console.log ('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE passed from WordPress: ' + getLangCode); 

    // so now you have the getLangCode, you can use it for your conditional
    if (getLangCode === 'en') {
        var imagesPath = 'https://website-domain.com/file-name.jpg';
    } else if (getLangCode === 'fr') {
        var imagesPath = 'https://website-domain.com/fr/file-name.jpg';
    } 
  }
}(jQuery));
```

This way, you can get any needed variables from WordPress PHP to be passed to your JS.

Comment: Worked, i'm glad i learn something new today. I have updated your answer to the one that works. The language code has to be `en`, `fr` and not `en-US`, `fr-FR`. Thanks so much for shedding lights to this

Answer (score 1):

Try to:
1) Remove this line:

```
var getLangCode = <?php echo '"' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE . '"' ; ?>; //WPML code to detect site's language. Getting error on this line
```

2) Add this code to your `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_head', 'change_this_name');
function change_this_name() {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var getLangCode = <?php echo '"' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE . '"' ; ?>; //WPML code to detect site's language. Getting error on this line
  </script>
  <?php
};
```

Comment: Ooof.  This, while it will work, is _not_ the wordpress way.... see https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-php-data-and-strings-to-javascript-in-wordpress--wp-34699

Comment: Tested this method and it works as well but going with El Ackabar version as it more wordpress way as stated by cale_b. Thanks @Sergej